# command to show number of processors in UNIX

Tags: unix, solaris

I want to check the number of processors using by a particular process in unix solaris.  Which command we can use for that?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 2):

A single threaded process will only use at most one CPU and unless bounded to a [processor set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/psrset-1m/index.html) it can be any of them.

To know what CPUs a given process is using at a given time, you can run this command (replace pid is the process id):

```
prstat -p pid -n 65536 -c 0 1 | grep cpu
```

Remove the `| grep cpu` part to see all threads, including those currently sleeping.

Note that even multi-threaded processes will rarely use a lot of CPUs, if any, as they are often I/O bound, not CPU bound.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood his question I guess. I read it as "Check number of processors using a command".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `psrinfo -v` for that.

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: /proc/cpuinfo is a Linux feature. `prsinfo -v` doesn't tell which process is using which cpu.